# normalizing real world data inside the canvas wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, normalization

I am working in a project in which I have to visualize certain points in real world coordinates into canvas inside ViewBox. Below is a sample of the data collection:

```
    X               Y
-40085.119      266560.373  
-40084.72       266560.736
-40083.51165    266559.4097
-41606.37001    263437.3891
-40098.72351    266327.5417
-40075.57653    266399.5039
-40076.09771    266398.6382
-40629.41856    265374.2896
-40698.41477    265214.1637
```

To convert the real world data to fit inside the canvas. I am calling the following function.

```
public double changeScale(double point, double min, double max, double size){
    double convertedValue;
    convertedValue = (point - min) / (max - min);
    convertedValue *= size;
    return convertedValue;
}
```

I use the stated function as follows:

```
sc.changeScale(x, xmax, xmax, mycanvas.Width)
sc.changeScale(y, ymax, ymin, mycanavs.Height)
```

xmin, xmax and ymin, ymax are taken out from the table of real time data. Size of my canvas is 1280 X 720. For example: if an element has coordinate (XMax, YMax) then, it will be plotted on (1280,720) and likewise, if an element has coordinate (XMin, XMax), then it will be plotted on (0,0).
This is still working but I found that this is not correct because the noramlized map I am getting is stretched which is inaccurate visualization of real world. I have compared mine with another software's result. The following image is what I have created:
[image: My result]

My expected result is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to maintain the aspect ratio. This means you'll have to change the scale with the same `size` for both X and Y.

First find the Maximum-X size and Maximum-Y size, then take the larger one and use it as size.

**UPDATE**

1. Find the minimum X, maximum X, minimum Y and maximum Y of the entire set.
2. Find the maximum between (MaxX - MinX) and (MaxY - MinY).
3. Use that value as `scale`.

Comment: Can you eleborate more, please?

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that in order to maintain aspect ratio, you must multiply both X axis and Y axis values by the same amount, and that's what my answer tries to explain how to do.

Comment: I followed your answer and but I am stuck at using the value as scale. I used ratio of the (XMax - XMin)/(YMax - YMin) to scale. i did multiply both by same ratio but it just made it smaller.

Comment: Don't divide. Take the maximum. The division is just to know the aspect ratio. It is useless in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Now, it is behaving as I want.